# Enable/Disbale Validation in ASP .net MVC 3

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a HTML form and within that form I have a DropDownList and a Button that can post to my action method. I want to disable the validation when the post is made by my DropDownList and enable it when it is made by the button.

In my action method I can differentiate, which one is making the post but I can not disable the validation.

I tried to set ValidateRequest = false but it didn't work. I don't want to use Ajax call at this stage.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Html.DropDownList(..., ..., new { disableValidation = "true" })
```